# Can't find specifications or compatible upgrades for motherboard

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I'm currently looking to upgrade my desktop, but I can't seem to find anything about my motherboard. I currently have a DX4850-41c(old, I'm aware), and the motherboard is MB.GBL01.002. I know the socket is 1155, but I'm afraid if I put an i5 processor, it won't be compatible. The only information I found is this motherboard only supports up to 16gb using all 4 slots (Crucial site)

Answer (score -1):

Meh, Gateway PCs. I can't find any specifications for you either. Go figure.

What I can tell you is that your PC can only handle [2nd Gen Core](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/59134/2nd-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors#@All) CPUs. BUT, without the specifications, we can't be certain *which* of those CPUs are actually compatible. That's important because some PCs/motherboards don't support all the CPUs you'd expect them to.

Your best bet is to contact Gateway. Give them your model numbers and ask them for a "supported/compatible CPU list".

Comment: Yea I figured. I'm mainly using this for editing and rendering, so I'm looking at an i5. Thanks anyway!